# How to Split an ArrayList in Android Using JAVA?

Tags: java, android, arraylist, split

Here is the code to put values in ArrayList and I am unable to split the arraylist with ",". Can someone please help me as to how to achieve this task ?

```
           spinnerArrayList = new ArrayList<String>();
           spinnerArrayList.add(menuFieldInstance.getFieldValues());
           Log.i("spinnerArrayList",""+spinnerArrayList);  
          //for(int j=0;j<spinnerArrayList.size();j++)
          //{
          Log.i("spinnerArrayList after splitting ,",""+spinnerArrayList.get(0).split(","));
           //}
```

Here is the Logcat of Spinner ArrayList and SpinnerArrayList after splitting.............

> 02-10 22:00:48.285: I/spinnerArrayList(19378): [0100~Avon & Somerset,0200~Bedfordshire,0300~Cambridgeshire,0400~Cheshire,0500~City of London,0600~Cleveland,0700~Cumbria,0800~Derbyshire,0900~Devon & Cornwall,1000~Dorset,1100~Durham,1200~Essex,1300~Gloucestershire,1400~Greater Manchester,1500~Hampshire,1600~Hertfordshire,1700~Humberside,1800~Kent,1900~Lancashire,2000~Leicestershire,2100~Linconshire,2200~Merseyside,2300~Metropolitan,2400~Norfolk,2500~Northamptonshire,2600~Northumbria,2700~North Yorkshire,2800~Nottinghamshire,2900~South Yorkshire,3000~Staffordshire,3100~Suffolk,3200~Surrey,3300~Sussex,3400~Thames Valley,3500~Warwickshire,3600~West Mercia,3700~West Midlands,3800~West Yorkshire,3900~Wiltshire,4000~Dyfed,4100~Gwent,4200~North Wales,4300~South Wales,4400~Royal Ulster,4500~Strathclyde,4600~Central Scotland,4700~Dumfries and Galloway,4800~Fife,4900~Grampian,5000~Lothian and Borders,5100~Northern Scotland,5200~Tayside,5300~Gurnsey,5400~States of Jersey,5500~Isle of Man,NO~No Police Response,THAM~THAMES VALLEY,WEST~WEST MIDLANDS POLICE,5600~Buckinghamshire]
>   02-10 22:00:48.285: I/spinnerArrayList after splitting ,(19378): [Ljava.lang.String;@41b9a498

Comment: split return one array of String, so if you want get value of that you need log one index of that not log all array like this.

Comment: can u give me sample code or edit my code

Comment: Arraylist contains discrete elements, you don't "split" it, it is already "splitted". Just use `get()` with an index.

Comment: `spinnerArrayList.get(0).split(",")[i]` where `i` is `int` position in array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
// try to print this way then you getting actual value at index becz your try to print String[] object rather each index value so do this way
spinnerArrayList = new ArrayList<String>();
spinnerArrayList.add("");
for (int i=0;i<spinnerArrayList.size();i++){
        String[] splitedValue = spinnerArrayList.get(i).split(",");
        for (int j=0;j<splitedValue.length;j++){
            Log.i(i+" at ArrayIndex "+j+" at splitedIndex Value is >> ",splitedValue[j]);
            String[] splitedValue1 = splitedValue[j].split("~");
            if(splitedValue1.length==1){
                continue;
            }
            for (int k=0;k<splitedValue1.length;k++){
                Log.i(j+" at splitedIndex "+k+" at splited1Index Value is >> ",splitedValue1[k]);
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: can u please help me i want to split the "~" in splitedValue[j]     but i am failed to do so ..... i have written     Log.i(j+" at ArrayIndex "+k+" at splitedIndex Value is >> ",splitedValue[k].split("~"));

Comment: i have edit it pls review the code and why u have put  if(splitedValue1.length ==1){
                   continue;
               }

Comment: Oky try to comment this code and see out put difference then you getting why should i put it...

Comment: can you give me your text which ever you want split ?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47145/discussion-between-user3233280-and-haresh)

Answer (score 1):

You can't split `ArrayList`. You can split `String`, e.g `"I am some String, you can split me".split(",")` will return an array of 2 Strings, but ArrayList is a data structure which holds some Strings and it doesn't mean that they are separated with comma. You can try to split each item of the list, e.g.

```
for (String s : spinnerArrayList) {
    String[] res = s.split(",");
    // do smth with res
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`spinnerArrayList.get(0).split(",")` doesn't split "the arrayList" it splits the string at index zero, and since the returned result is an array of strings - you can't concatenate it using the `+` operator to another string:

```
Log.i("spinnerArrayList after splitting ,",""+spinnerArrayList.get(0).split(","));
```

Read the splitted string into a String array first:

```
String[] arr = spinnerArrayList.get(0).split(",");
```

and then loop the array and print the values"

```
for(String val: arr){
    Log.i(val);
}
```